# How to select only an element of an array within a Mongoose.find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I've got these values in database:

```
{
    name: '1',
    values: [{
        subname: 'awesome'
    }, {
        surname: 'cool'
    }]
}
```

how could I filter the array with only the value I'm interested in?

I would like to get as result of my find:

```
{
    name: '1',
    values: [{
        subname: 'awesome'
    }]
}
```

I thought maybe there is a possibility with select? Something like

```
MyCollection.find({name: '1'}).select(BLACK_MAGIC);
```

Where `BLACK_MAGIC` filters my array with the values I'm interested in, in this example values.subname = 'awesome'

Thx in advance for any ideas

Side note: I'm interesting to solve this with Mongoose queries and functions, not a solution with a post javascript on the resulting array

Comment: Maybe [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) might be useful.

Comment: Thx @Mikey, look like you are right, the examples of the documentation seems to fit my needs...gonna study and try that!

Comment: @Mikey it kind of work but doesn't fulfill 100% what I'm looking for. Doing Collection.find({something}, {$elementMatch}) gonna return {_id, theElementMatched} but I would like to return {_id, everything else, theElementMatched}

Comment: I had my doubts about $elemMatch when I saw the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for this.

You would [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) so that each `values` object is in a separate document.

Then filter the results with [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

```
MyCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$values'
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            'values.subname': 'awesome'
        }
    },
    // EDIT
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            name: { 
                $first: "$name"
            },
            values: {
                $push: { subname: "$values.subname" }
            }
         }
    }
], function (err, results) {

});
```

If it works, you are little bit closer. The only thing is that `values` is an object, not an array of one object. You could probably use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) to get desired result.

Comment: cool thx for the answer. aggregation and unwind as you described did the job!